# App Bundle, In Dynamic Feature Module, Module available before install

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I try to implement dynamic feature module in my app. I have button in Activity. When user click I check module already installed or not. if not i start Install using startInstall(request). But I always goes to else state.

**Code**

```
    if (manager.installedModules.contains("sample")) {
-----> Always go to this block 
                Toast.makeText(this, "Already Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Intent().setClassName(packageName, "com.example.sample.SampleActivity")
                        .also {
                            startActivity(it)
                        }
            } else {
               // Never came to this state
                // Create request to install a feature module by name.
                val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addModule("sample")
                        .build()
                // Load and install the requested feature module.
                manager.startInstall(request)
            }
```

In Dynamic feature module I set `onDemand="true"`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
package="com.example.sample">

<dist:module
    dist:onDemand="true"
    dist:title="@string/title_sample">
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
</dist:module>

<application>
    <activity android:name="com.example.sample.SampleActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Because your package name contains "sample". that's why always you got this block, just change and check it.

Comment: No @PoovarasanSelvaraj,  dynamic feature already exist in my app that why its not crash when i startActivity

Answer (score 6):

Currently the only way to test your implementation of onDemand delivery is by uploading the .aab to the PlayStore.

The standard deployment from Android Studio deploys all modules to the attached device.

In a development environment the flow is correct, that the module is already installed when it's deployed to device.

As for code, take a look at the [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features), in particular the download and listener implementation of [MainActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/samples/dynamicfeatures/MainActivity.kt).

Comment: is any official documentation ?

Comment: There is documentation on [PlayCore](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore) but that currently doesn't mention the upload requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of testing dynamic feature modules locally, without being uploading it to play store, is to use **bundle-tool**.

bundle-tool uses a flag `--local-testing` which emulates the exact environment and the feature module can be seen downloading

```
./gradlew bundleDebug

bundletool build-apks --overwrite --local-testing --bundle path/to/bundle.aab --output path/to/apkset.apks

bundletool install-apks --apks path/to/apkset.apks
```

Refer to the following link for more details:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/local-development-and-testing-with-fakesplitinstallmanager-57083e1840a4

Answer (score -2):

```
add split="dynamic-feature-test" in your manifest
split="split_name" : Defines the name of the module, which your app specifies when requesting an on demand module using the Play Core Library.
```